# Cant Center text with materializecss

Tags: html, css

I am using the [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) for developing a html web app.

I am struggling using their helpers. I am trying to center my number and text:

[image]

For a better look at my code:

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css';
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m7">
    <div class="card valign-wrapper">
      <div class="card-content valign center" >
        <div class="row">
          <h3 class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2"> 406 </h3>
          <p class="center-align">Beers Tasted</p>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m7">
    <div class="card valign-wrapper">
      <div class="card-content valign center" >
        <div class="row">
          <h3 class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2"> 26 </h3>
          <p class="center-align">Breweries Visited</p>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using the class `center`:

```html
<div class="card-content valign center">
```

That class just adds `text-align: center`. That is, it centers inline content inside that block, but doesn't center the block itself.

To do that, you should use the class `center-block` instead:

```html
<div class="card-content valign center-block">
```

That class sets `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`. That centers the block (or the flex item, in this case; see [8.1. Aligning with auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)).

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css';
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m7">
    <div class="card valign-wrapper">
      <div class="card-content valign center-block" >
        <div class="row">
          <h3 class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2"> 406 </h3>
          <p class="center-align">Beers Tasted</p>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m7">
    <div class="card valign-wrapper">
      <div class="card-content valign center-block" >
        <div class="row">
          <h3 class="center-align orange-text text-darken-2"> 26 </h3>
          <p class="center-align">Breweries Visited</p>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by centering the `.card-content` div like this:

```
.card .card-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```